# Hard time with php associative array, numbers won't print?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am embarrass to ask this because it's seems so easy . forgive me.

the following php :

```
<?php
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$arrlength=count($cars);

$data = array();
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
    $data[(string)$x]=$cars[$x];
  }
  var_dump($data);
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

give me this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Volvo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "BMW"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Toyota"
}
["Volvo","BMW","Toyota"]
```

The dump looks great but when I encode it , it disappear,

But when I do `$data[$cars[$x]] = $x;` I get the opposite of what I want

```
array(3) {
  ["Volvo"]=>
  int(0)
  ["BMW"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Toyota"]=>
  int(2)
}
{"Volvo":0,"BMW":1,"Toyota":2}
```

But the number shows in the JSON what I really want is this:

```
{0:"Volvo", 1:"BMW", 2:"Toyota"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much easier way:

```
<?php
    $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
    $data = json_encode($cars, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
    print_r($data);
?>
```

will print:

```
{"0":"Volvo","1":"BMW","2":"Toyota"}
```

**EDIT:** To get what you're asking for, you'll need two things: (1) get array elements to start with 1;  and (2) have the whole array as a value for index `cars`. One way to get array to start with index 1 is to define an array with the first (index 0) element, which you then unset.  This removes existing element, but does not redefine the rest of the array.  Your code would look like this:

```
<?php
    $cars=array("","Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
    unset($cars[0]);
    $data = json_encode(array("cars" => $cars), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    print_r($data);
?>
```

This will produce

```
{"cars":{"1":"Volvo","2":"BMW","3":"Toyota"}}
```

I really don't know why you need this thing as an element of an array in itself, but you can just put square brackets around the output, as getting it by creating objects/arrays and then `json_encode`'ing it would be really painful:

```
$data = "[" . json_encode(array("cars" => $cars), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) . "]";
```

Comment: wow I this looks so simple what does `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` I have never heard of it

Comment: @AlPacino `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` essentially converts all arrays to object representation with indices as keys. Have a look at this page: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: I like your approach I just dont know how to use it , my goal was to get this `[{"cars":{"1":"Volvo","2":"BMW","3":"Toyota"}}]`, please advice

Comment: @AlPacino I updated my answer with the solution for you.

Comment: You earned the green tick boss!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is JSON encoded object. This can be achieved by this code:

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$arrlength=count($cars);

$data = new StdClass;
for ($x=0; $x<$arrlength; $x++) {
    $data->{(string)$x} = $cars[$x];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

[json_encode has a second (optional) parameter](http://www.php.net/json_encode) that can be used to control the behaviour, you are looking for JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, which can be used like this:

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
print json_encode($cars, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

{"0":"Volvo","1":"BMW","2":"Toyota"}
```

Comment: I like your approach I just dont know how to use it , my goal was to get this `[{"cars":{"1":"Volvo","2":"BMW","3":"Toyota"}}]`, please advice

Comment: json_encode(array('cars' => $cars), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); perhaps then?

Comment: so close I get `{"cars":{"0":"Volvo","1":"BMW","2":"Toyota"}}` it's just missing the brackets for array